# PDO constant to group array by key and value as array of values MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, pdo

I have items in my database, with a date in each row like this (UNIX TIMESTAMP):

```
|  id | date                       |
+-----+----------------------------+
|  1  | 2014-05-23 00:07:15.000000 |
|  2  | 2014-05-23 00:07:15.000000 |
|  3  | 2014-06-23 00:07:15.000000 |
|  4  | 2014-06-23 00:07:15.000000 |
|  5  | 2014-07-23 00:07:15.000000 |
|  6  | 2014-07-23 00:07:15.000000 |
```

I want to fetch them, and group them by date and then build an array with a PDO so the array will look like this:

```
array(3) {
    ["2014-05-23 00:07:15.000000"] =>
    array(2) {
        ["id"] => 1
        ["id"] => 2
    }
    ["2014-06-23 00:07:15.000000"] =>
    array(2) {
        ["id"] => 3
        ["id"] => 4
    }
    ["2014-07-23 00:07:15.000000"] =>
    array(2) {
        ["id"] => 5
        ["id"] => 6
    }
}
```

So all columns are grouped to **each** key.

```
$query = $pdo->query('SELECT DATE a, id FROM vote_statistics GROUP BY a');
$query->execute();
```

I can do this, by ***building the array manually looping through fetch results***, but is there a way in PDO to use fetchAll which will construct my array like this? *a constant?*

Comment: Check `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` and `PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR` whether they suit your needs.

Comment: @rr- I tried `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`, it doesn't do the right job for my case.